# JUnit not working with Lombok - annotation processing doesn't seem to work for test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, lombok, annotation-processing

I have a problem with Lombok and JUnit.

I am using `IntelliJ Idea`, the latest one, with `Lombok` plugin installed and annotation processing enabled.

I have an entity class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String email;

}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.10'
    testCompile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.10'
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10"
}
```

And finally, the test case:

```
@Test
public void whenCheckIfPresent_thenOk() {
    User user = User.builder().name("John").email("sf@sf.pl").build();
    Optional<User> opt = Optional.ofNullable(user);
    assertTrue(opt.isPresent());

    assertEquals(user.getEmail(), opt.get().getEmail());
}
```

When I am trying to run this test I get below error:

```
IdeaProjects\Tutoriale\src\test\java\optionals\OptionalsTest.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        User user = User.builder().name("John").email("sf@sf.pl").build();
                        ^
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class User
IdeaProjects\Tutoriale\src\test\java\optionals\OptionalsTest.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals(user.getEmail(), opt.get().getEmail());
                         ^
  symbol:   method getEmail()
  location: variable user of type User
IdeaProjects\Tutoriale\src\test\java\optionals\OptionalsTest.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals(user.getEmail(), opt.get().getEmail());
                                               ^
  symbol:   method getEmail()
  location: class User
```

It seems that annotation processing isn't working, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: This might help you 
https://palesz.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/howto-maven-lombok-and-aspectj-together/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What Gradle version are you using? This issue was seen in Gradle version 5.4.1.

For Lombok annotations in test source sets, you need to add Lombok to two dependency configurations:

**testCompileOnly** '...'
**testAnnotationProcessor** '...'

In the same way, as compileOnly and annotationProcessor, the first one makes the annotations available to the code and the second one activates annotation processing during compilation

You could try the dependency as below,

```
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
```

Reference: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle[Lombok doc](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1945)

More information can be found in the below location,

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1945

Comment: Finally, among all answers I tried from other questions to the same topic, this one worked for me! Adding the annotationProcessor was the key ingredient that was missing :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still relevant for Intellij 2023.2.5;  was trying to figure out why lombok wasn't working, but adding the missing "annotationProcessor" line in gradle fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You've used incorrect dependency `testAnnotationProcessor` it should be `annotationProcessor`, see [lombock-gradle doc](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle). After fixing gradle file you'll be able to build it with terminal. 
Also it could be still failed in IDE because of lombok requires to enable annotation processing for IDE (check your IDE documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "${lombok_version}"

with

compileClasspath group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "${lombok_version}"

worked for me!