# lombok annotation and test

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I use Spring Boot 3 with Intellij and Lombok.

In my `build.gradle` I have

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.2.0'

    runtimeOnly group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc11', version: '21.9.0.0'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}
```

In my test class, I use this annotation.

```
@Log4j2
```

I have no editor error.

When I try to build, I get the error cannot find symbol log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866765/building-with-lomboks-slf4j-and-intellij-cannot-find-symbol-log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit not working with Lombok - annotation processing doesn't seem to work for test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426699/junit-not-working-with-lombok-annotation-processing-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-t)